# Stop Tkinter from opening a second window when importing drawing function

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am having an issue that I am having trouble resolving. I am making a Python interface with Tkinter that allows the user to draw a predefined figure with some parameters (number and length). The predefined figure function "tree" is in a second python file. The app runs fine if the "tree" function is in the main python file i.e everything draws in one window. If I put the figure "tree" in a second python file (figures.py) and try to import it the app will create a second window and the tree figure will draw there instead of the intended main window. How can I reference and import the function so that it draws in the main app window. Thanks!

main python file

```
import turtle
import tkinter
from tkinter.ttk import *
import figures

# Main function is defined.
def main():
    # Set root and create canvas
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Draw")
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=700)
    canvas.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

    # create a turtle to draw on the canvas 
    pen = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
    screen = pen.getscreen()

    # Set screen co-ordinates.
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-200, -700, 800, 700)
    screen.bgcolor("grey")

    # Draw frame  
    frame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="white")
    frame.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

    pointLabel = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Fractal", bg="white", )
    pointLabel.pack()

    # make the dropdown for fractal  list
    turtleNames = ["Tree", "Dandelion"]
    turtleStr = tkinter.StringVar()
    turtleList = OptionMenu(frame, turtleStr, turtleNames[0], *turtleNames)
    turtleList.pack()

    numberLabel = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Number")
    numberLabel.pack()

    # the entry widget must be given a string.
    number = tkinter.StringVar()
    numberEntry = tkinter.Entry(frame, textvariable=number)
    numberEntry.pack()
    number.set(str(3))

    lengthLabel = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Length")
    lengthLabel.pack()

    # User sets length
    length = tkinter.StringVar()
    lengthEntry = tkinter.Entry(frame, textvariable=length)
    lengthEntry.pack()
    length.set(str(200))

    def drawHandler():
        # get the value from orderStr and make int
        num = int(number.get())

        # get the value from lengthStr and make int
        len = int(length.get())

        figures.tree(num, len)

    # Event handler to clear canvas for a new drawing
    def clearHandler():
        pen.clear()

    # This is an event handler. Handling the quit button press results in quitting the application.
    def quitHandler():
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()

    # Draw Buttons

    # presses of the "Draw" button.
    drawButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Draw", command=drawHandler)
    drawButton.pack()

    # presses of the "Clear" button.
    clearButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Clear", command=clearHandler)
    clearButton.pack()

    # presses of the "Quit" button.
    quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Quit", command=quitHandler)
    quitButton.pack()

    # tells the application to enter its event processing loop
    tkinter.mainloop()

# Python jumps right here after executing the def main() line. These two lines tell
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

figures.py for storing predefined designs

```
from turtle import *

pen = Pen()

screen = Screen()


# 1st figure Tree
def tree(n, l):
    if n == 0 or l < 2:
        return
    # endif
    pen.forward(l)
    pen.left(45)
    tree(n - 1, l / 2)
    pen.right(90)
    tree(n - 1, l / 2)
    pen.left(45)
    pen.backward(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app runs fine if the "tree" function is in the main python file
>   i.e everything draws in one window. If I put the figure "tree" in a
>   second python file (figures.py) and try to import it the app will
>   create a second window and the tree figure will draw there instead of
>   the intended main window.

The problem is that figures.py is setting up a turtle environment independent of the main program -- don't let it.  Pass in to the figures.py functions whatever they need to operate in the main program's turtle environment:

**figures.py**

```
# 1st figure Tree
def tree(pen, number, length):
    if number == 0 or length < 2:
        return

    pen.forward(length)
    pen.left(45)
    tree(pen, number - 1, length / 2)
    pen.right(90)
    tree(pen, number - 1, length / 2)
    pen.left(45)
    pen.backward(length)

# test this code standalone
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import turtle

    tree(turtle.getpen(), 5, 100)  # test using default turtle

    turtle.exitonclick()
```

The code at the bottom of the file is so you can test this file independently.  When imported into the main program, it will be ignored.  Now we just need a small change to the main program:

**main python file**

```
def drawHandler():
    # get the value from orderStr and make int
    number_int = int(number.get())

    # get the value from lengthStr and make int
    length_int = int(length.get())

    figures.tree(pen, number_int, length_int)
```

I changed the variable names as you were redefining Python's built-in `len` function.